# EJB3 remote invocation throws ClassCastException

Tags: ejb-3.0, rmi, classcastexception

Somehow when I try a remote remote EJB3 call the ClassCastException is thrown.

**Server:**

```
public interface CardManager extends Manager {
     public CardCheckResponse check(CardCheckRequest request);
}


@Remote
public interface RMICardManagerRemote extends CardManager {
     static String CARD_CHECK_RMI_REMOTE_JNDI = "CardCheckRMI/remote";
}


@Stateless
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = RMICardManagerRemote.CARD_CHECK_RMI_REMOTE_JNDI)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class RealRMICardManager implements RMICardManagerRemote {
    private CardManager cardManager = injector.getInstance(CardManager.class);

    @Override
    public CardCheckResponse check(CardCheckRequest request) {
    return cardManager.check(request);
    }

}
```

**Client:**

```
InitialContext remoteContext = new InitialContext(PropertiesUtil.getCardCheckProp());
RMICardManagerRemote rmiCardManagerRemote = (RMICardManagerRemote) remoteContext.lookup(RMICardManagerRemote.CARD_CHECK_RMI_REMOTE_JNDI);

//throws ClassCastException
CardCheckResponse cardCheckResponse = rmiCardManagerRemote.check(cardCheckRequest);
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.cardcheck.dto.CardCheckResponse cannot be cast to com.cardcheck.dto.CardCheckResponse
    at $Proxy307.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxx.cardCheck(RechargeAdapter.java:267)
```

I've checked if it was duplicate jar, but is not the case. Does anyone have any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem is caused by JBoss's unified class loader. I solved my problem creating a custom loader in jboss-app.xml:

```
<loader-repository> com.cardcheck loader = cardCheck heard </ loader-repository>
```